# How do I connect to the internet?

Tags: internet

When I installed Ubuntu I forgot to add a wifi connection and under the network tab it won’t show wifi connections. Ethernet doesn’t work ether. Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci`? This will share the models of your network devices, making it more likely that you receive an answer 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take help of nmcli utility just enter the command `nmcli r` to check whether your NIC is supported or not if no, then a error will occur and if it's supported you will see all your wireless adapters and NICs if they are disabled just enter the command `nmcli r <your wireless adapter stated there> on` or you can enable all by entering `nmcli r all on` and now check for wireless connections using command `nmcli connection` and you will see what networks are present there. If you want more elaboration then ask me.